# Setting task scheduler to run when online

Tags: windows-8.1, scheduled-tasks

I have my Windows Update set to "never check for updates" on Windows 8.1, but since I still want the Defender definitions update daily, I created a task to get them.

However, I have a question about choosing the appropriate trigger/setting. I want it to run when the computer goes online. Does anyone know how I can set this?

Comment: "Online" as in on the Internet, or "online" as in there's an active network connection?

Comment: I mean "online", when having internet connection.

Comment: If this is not the best way to go, please let me know the trigger you'd use.